# Realtek 8822CE wifi not working but bluetooth working

Tags: wireless, lenovo, realtek

I tried to install both Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and Ubuntu 19.10 but I'm facing the same issue: I am able to use bluetooth but wifi adapter is not detected.
I checked on my Lenovo laptop's BIOS and I have "Secure boot" disabled so I really don't know what to do. 
Can you please help me? Thanks.

This is the output of the command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

`01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c82f]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:c02f]
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Sandisk Corp Device [15b7:5005] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Sandisk Corp Device [15b7:5005]
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no`

While the output of the command `dmesg | grep rtw` is empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Realtek RTL8822CE is unable to detect WiFi networks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180714/realtek-rtl8822ce-is-unable-to-detect-wifi-networks)

Comment: unfortunately not. I tried that but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command. And also `dmesg | grep rtw`.

Comment: ok I just added the output of the commands you requested

Comment: Why do you think it is rtl8822ce? It is not detected by kernel at all.

Comment: because on windows 10 under the device manager, it shows up as "Realtek 8822CE"

Comment: I couldn't find any drivers that support `[10ec:c82f]`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I finally found a solution. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1228462/183402).

In short: it turns out the driver that should support this hardware (rtw88) was available and compatible with this hardware already in kernel > 5.2, but it is not set to recognize this hardware.

To fix the problem I had to compile linux kernel with a small modification to the source code:

Locate the file: `./linux/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/pci.c`, and edit it. Look for the string `'0xC822'`, and replace it with `'0xC82F'`

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the solution from yaron160 works.

I used the code here instead to install the relevant driver module: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88. In the code dated 18th May, the file to be changed is rtw8822ce.c instead of pci.c

Hope this answer is helpful

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This is a good catch, but not a full answer. The other answer may be removed, etc. Please write a full answer, or sugest an edit to the @yaron160 answer.

Comment: And also I don't see `rtw_8822ce.mod.c` file there.

Comment: Where did you get the code dated today?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Incomplete and low quality answers are likely to be deleted by moderators. An link only answer is considered incomplete, as links change or fail after a time. Consider editing your answer and make it self standing and complete. This will help others.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I've had a long day today trying to find the answer. Will update sometime soon (hopefully tomorrow) to be used for my future reference as well. There is a clear set of steps I ended up following that I'll list down

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks. Edited my original post. 
I just checked out the latest code (dated today) :)

Comment: I see that the latest commit was on May 15. I fixed the file name.

Comment: Thanks again for your kind inputs Pilot6 and @user68186

Answer (score 0):

My solution is for debian(debian 10.5) but since I didn't see my solution anywhere in forums I'm gonna post it if it is not against the rules.

Did it on a Matebook D14 2020 CPU AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with a realtek 8822CE network card.
I had no display without a new linux kernel so I installed the 5.7.X if you want any info on this feel free to DM me.

First you have to edit your /etc/apt/sources.list and add :

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free
```

then
`apt update`
this will allow us to download the firmware

```
https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/firmware-realtek
```

back to your terminal install the package by typing :

```
apt-get -t buster-backports install firmware-realtek
```

it is important to download with buster-backports, the version in synaptic is not updated and doesn't have the ce firmware. Now you can check if everything is fine with synaptic (if you don't have it I suggest to download it)

```
synaptic-pkexec
```

search for "realtek" in the searchbar, you should have the latest version including 8822ce firmware(check the description).

it could probably work on ubuntu but I haven't tried it.

now you can reboot and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Linux and had the same problem with my asus tuf gaming a17 laptop.  The lwfinger repository was no longer available, but found the driver elsewhere on github.  Anyway,  installing the driver didn't help,  here it was because i was on firmware 1.173. Search for Linux firmware archive and update to 1.187 (1.187.3 is the current stable supported)  make sure to use the 187_all deb. This got me on track and was able to finally use wifi in Linux.  I didn't post links because it was a learning experience for me and i think all would benefit from that.  Synaptic didn't help by the way.